# Adding text after image composite, html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have combined two images and some text using html5 canvas, but I can't seem to position the images the same way I can with the text. With the text I just changed the x and y properties to position it on the canvas, but this does not seem to work with my two images. They are just set at 0, 0 (top left) regardless.

```
<canvas width="850" height="450" id="canvas"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('<%= image_url(@entry.picture(:small)) %>', main);
var img2 = loadImage("<%= image_url('overlay.png') %>", main);

var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if(imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    }

}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.font="30px sans-serif";
        ctx.fillText("<%= full_name(@entry.user) %>", 60, 435);
        ctx.fillStyle="#333333";
    };
    img.src = src;

    return img;

}
</script>
```

In my head, the line `ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0,);` should position the image when the values of 0 and 0 are changed, but it does not. My Javascript knowledge isn't great, so there is probably something obvious, but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many styles of code used to preload images to insure they are fully loaded before you try to draw them using `drawImage`:

[image]

Here's annotated code and a Demo:

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/face1.png");
imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/face2.png");

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
startLoadingAllImages(imagesAreNowLoaded);

// Create a new Image() for each item in imageURLs[]
// When all images are loaded, run the callback (==imagesAreNowLoaded)
function startLoadingAllImages(callback){

  // iterate through the imageURLs array and create new images for each
  for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
    // create a new image an push it into the imgs[] array
    var img = new Image();
    imgs.push(img);
    // when this image loads, call this img.onload
    img.onload = function(){ 
      // this img loaded, increment the image counter
      imagesOK++; 
      // if we've loaded all images, call the callback
      if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
        callback();
      }
    };
    // notify if there's an error
    img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
    // set img properties
    img.src = imageURLs[i];
  }      
}

// All the images are now loaded
// Do drawImage & fillText
function imagesAreNowLoaded(){

  // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
  // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

  ctx.font="30px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle="#333333";

  // drawImage the first image (face1.png) from imgs[0]
  // and fillText its label below the image
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],0,10);
  ctx.fillText("face1.png", 0, 135);

  // drawImage the first image (face2.png) from imgs[1]
  // and fillText its label below the image
  ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],200,10);
  ctx.fillText("face2.png", 210, 135);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this! Really helpful!